# Separate the layout to two activities, fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, admob

i want to separate my layout in two parts:
the bottom for ads, and the other part to the app(few activities).
why i want to do that? because i want the ad appears every time even when new activity started.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/plVeO.png
i realized that is possible to do that with fragment.
 I have few questions about fragment:
 fragment can hold two activities?
 can i start a fragment like activity with intent?

---

The main question is how TO SEPARATE THE LAYOUT IN TO PARTS while using fragment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, fragment can not have two Activities, but vise versa - yes. For dynamic actions with fragments create xml file in which will 2 frames, one attached to the bottom, and read about http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="3" >
</FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

in Activity:

```
    NewFragment fragment = new NewFragment();
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.frame1, fragment);
    ft.commit();
```

Or, static in xml:

```
<LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<fragment android:name="com.example.android.fragments.HeadlinesFragment"
          android:id="@+id/headlines_fragment"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<fragment android:name="com.example.android.fragments.ArticleFragment"
          android:id="@+id/article_fragment"
          android:layout_weight="3"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: how do i place the content from an fragmentactivity to the framelayout? and where the fragment is taking place with this code?

Comment: `@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
     super.onCreate(arg0);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     NewFragment fragment = (NewFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.headlines_fragment);`

Comment: please send to me your NewFragment class, mine crash. thank you!

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry, I didn't have possibility to answer you, do you need `NewFragment` class yet?

Answer (score 0):

you could make one parent activity which will hold adverts and have free space for content, than you inherit that activity and fill up content from inherited one, maybe inflate other layouts in base. if you will be using more than one layout for content you could make also parent layout and "inherit" it as well.
or you can use one activity which would hold adverts and use fragments for content.